# How does MongoDB compare, in speed, to a standard tree implemented in C++?

Tags: performance, mongodb, data-structures

I am wondering if anyone has looked at the speed comparison between using mongodb and a standard C++ tree. I am currently building a project that uses a tree structure to store its data in RAM. As I understand, JSON has a similar kind of structuring where nodes of a tree are inside a JSON object, like

```
my_tree : {
    node1 : [
        innerNode1: {},
        innerNode2: {},
        innerNode3: {}
    ],
    node2 : [
    ... data
    ],
}
```

Which is very similar to the tree like data structure that I am implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An in-core tree will always be faster. Fetching a node typically costs one (maybe more) cache miss. That is a few nanoseconds. For disk-based tree nodes, the latency will be 5-10 ms for magnetic disks (plus the cost of one or more system calls). For network-based storage it could even be 100 ms or more for remote storage.

Things get worse if you want to *walk* the tree: every node will cost a round trip for disk- or network storage, or a cache miss for in-memory objects.

The art of disk-based object storage is to **avoid** this *row-at-atime* processing. SQL databases today have some support for recursive queries. But I'm afraid noSQL DBMSses won't have that.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a test and time it yourself. The answer depends on the efficiency of your tree structure implementation, of course!

Comment: I'm just curious to see if someone else has done something similar.

Answer (score 1):

A pure C++ tree implementation may be faster and may have way less overhead, because it doesn't have to deal with things from DB world, like atomicity, journal, concurrency, IPC, parsing driver messages (this may be almost the same thing as IPC)...

But your tree-like implementation may not have all types of queries that MongoDB give to you. Your implementation also may be fully RAM-based, meaning that you can't process that much ammount of documents.